# Python clearing text file if file size exceed 10kb

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

i was making a program that writes to a file for automation using python
but when i write 10kb worth of text it clears the text file and writes again
it might be a limitation on python which makes it that your computer doesnt fill up but in this case i want it to write essential text.

Can this limitation be bypass?

```
def WRITETOFILE(str):
   file_data = GETFILECONTENTS()
   with open("FILELOCATION", "w") as f:
       file_data += f"\n{str}"
       f.write(file_data)
def GETFILECONTENTS():
   with open("FILELOCATION". "r") as f:
       return f.read()
```

code for writing what thing it writes

```
def myFunction():
    #CODE TO FIND TEXT TO WRITE
    WRTIETOFILE(TEXT)
def getTEXT():
   myFunction()
while True:
    c += 1
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=getTEXT)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=getTEXT)
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=getTEXT)
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=getTEXT)
    t5 = threading.Thread(target=getTEXT)
    t6 = threading.Thread(target=getTEXT)
    t7 = threading.Thread(target=getTEXT)
    t8 = threading.Thread(target=getTEXT)
    t9 = threading.Thread(target=getTEXT)
    t10 = threading.Thread(target=getTEXT)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t4.start()
    t5.start()
    t6.start()
    t7.start()
    t8.start()
    t9.start()
    t10.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    t4.join()
    t5.join()
    t6.join()
    t7.join()
    t8.join()
    t9.join()
    t10.join()
```

Comment: Can you show us the program? Format the code into the question

Comment: What exactly would you expect it to do when you use ```"w"``` in ```with open("FILELOCATION", "w") as f:```?

Comment: `open("FILELOCATION", "w")` deletes the file and creates a new one. `open("FILELOCATION", "a")` creates _or_ appends to an existing file. Is that the problem? And, no, python doesn't care if you fill up your file system. It will happily write until the disk is full, then raise on exception.

Comment: There's at least one syntax error in the code you've posted. Are you sure that this code is representative of the code your running?

Comment: When you use `f.read()` you're not guaranteed to get the whole file contents.  Keep reading until it returns nothing.

Comment: @MarkRansom Are you sure about that? The docs for [`read`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) say _"When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned; it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory."_

Comment: i am using threading so its probably writing to a file while another thread is removing the file so it gets overwritten i am new to threading so how can i check if a text file is empty?

Comment: @H1387XD That is a completely different scenario that the one you've posted in your question. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that represents the actual problem you're facing

Comment: If you want to write to a single file with multiple threads, you run the risk that one thread may interrupt another, interleaving content. If you open the file multiple times, each will have their own file pointers and will also tend to overwrite. You may want to lock the file and only allow a single writer at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it for some reason i can't reproduce the problem and it just fixes it self

i am sorry for the inconvenience

i think its because when i exit the program the file hasnt done writing

but even if i dont exit the program the file still clears

*sorry for bad grammar*

Comment: can someone close this question?